# How to implement three legged OAuth with MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to use ASP .NET MVC 4's built in OAuth functionality to connect to QuickBooks.  The problem (I mean, uh challenge) is that the built in templates (facebook, google, etc.) all offer two legged authorization.  QuickBooks uses three.  As a result, this has really been stomping a mud hole in my butt.

The good news is that QuickBooks provides an MVC 3 example.  You may find it here:

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Implement_OAuth_in_Your_App

The most relevant code that's causing me problems is here:

```
    private String consumerSecret, consumerKey, oauthLink, RequestToken, TokenSecret, oauth_callback_url;

    /// <summary>
    /// Action Result for Index, This flow will create OAuthConsumer Context using Consumer key and Consuler Secret key
    /// obtained when Application is added at intuit workspace. It creates OAuth Session out of OAuthConsumer and Calls 
    /// Intuit Workpsace endpoint for OAuth.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Redirect Result.</returns>
    public RedirectResult Index()
    {
        oauth_callback_url = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["oauth_callback_url"];
        consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"];
        consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"];
        oauthLink = Constants.OauthEndPoints.IdFedOAuthBaseUrl;
        IToken token = (IToken)Session["requestToken"];
        IOAuthSession session = CreateSession();
        IToken requestToken = session.GetRequestToken();
        Session["requestToken"] = requestToken;
        RequestToken = requestToken.Token;
        TokenSecret = requestToken.TokenSecret;

        oauthLink = Constants.OauthEndPoints.AuthorizeUrl + "?oauth_token=" + RequestToken + "&oauth_callback=" + UriUtility.UrlEncode(oauth_callback_url);
        return Redirect(oauthLink);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Access Token
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns OAuth Session</returns>
    protected IOAuthSession CreateSession()
    {
        OAuthConsumerContext consumerContext = new OAuthConsumerContext
        {
            ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
            SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.HmacSha1
        };

        OAuthSession s = new OAuthSession(consumerContext,
                                        Constants.OauthEndPoints.IdFedOAuthBaseUrl + Constants.OauthEndPoints.UrlRequestToken,
                                        oauthLink,
                                        Constants.OauthEndPoints.IdFedOAuthBaseUrl + Constants.OauthEndPoints.UrlAccessToken);

        return s;
    }
```

From that, you can see that the MVC 3 example creates a session and grabs a request token.  My immediate problem is locating the bit of code in MVC 4 where I can retrieve this request token. I *think* it is in my AccountController here:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
    //
    // Go to me first!!!

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }


    //
    // Go to me second!!!

    internal class ExternalLoginResult : ActionResult
    {
        public ExternalLoginResult(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            Provider = provider;
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public string Provider { get; private set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; private set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if(Provider.Equals("Quickbooks Online")){
                // oauthLink = Constants.OauthEndPoints.AuthorizeUrl + "?oauth_token=" + RequestToken + "&oauth_callback=" + UriUtility.UrlEncode(oauth_callback_url);
                // oauthLink    "https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token=qyprdvh1kZ3dpyobhKfJ54C10xPJPDy0vtwdNCeZmUmbLJdr&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A50671%2FOauthResponse" string
                string requestToken = "";  // How do I get this?
                string oauthCallback = context.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme + "/OauthResponse";

    //
    // Now do I get a request token?  How?

                string returnUrl = "https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin" + "?oauth_token=" + requestToken + "&oauth_callback=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oauthCallback);
                OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, returnUrl);
            }
            else{
                OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);
            }
        }
    }
```

But from here I get lost.  Any help would be appreciated.  I've googled alot and I'd guess I've got somewhere north of 40 hours invested so far trying to get this to work.

Thanks,
Will

Answer (score 2):

Intuit Partner Platform currently supports OAuth1.0a.  The first leg in the 3-legged OAuth is the procurement of the OAuth request token.

I haven't used MVC4's OAuthWebSecurity; but, based on what I quickly gleaned from the doc/source code, it seems like you need to create a distinct 'QuickBooksClient' (and, open source it?).  I'd follow the [LinkedInClient class](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/Clients/OAuth/LinkedInClient.cs) as a recipe.  From the [IPP docs](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0020_Connect/0010_From_Within_Your_App/Implement_OAuth_in_Your_App), the OAuth endpoints are:

Get Request token: https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token
Login Page: https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin
Get Access token: https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've put this on the back burner and turned my attention to some other problems.  Quickbooks contacted me and said they'd be coming out with an example sometime this year.  I've got time to wait for it.